# Avoiding "warning C4005: 'INT8_MIN': macro redefinition" when using flex/bison in a C++ project

Tags: c++, c, bison, flex-lexer

I have a C++ project that is using flex/bison.

The generated code for the lexer includes the section below:

```
/* C99 systems have <inttypes.h>. Non-C99 systems may or may not. */

#if defined (__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L

#include <inttypes.h>
typedef int8_t flex_int8_t;
// ... more typedefs here

#else

typedef signed char flex_int8_t;
// ... more typedefs here

/* Limits of integral types. */
#ifndef INT8_MIN
#define INT8_MIN               (-128)
#endif
// ... more defines here

#endif /* ! C99 */
```

Windows compilations warn you about all those integral types already being defined in `stdint.h` (e.g. `Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include\stdint.h(49,1)`).

I understand this happens because C++ compilations don't set `_STDC_VERSION__`.

I have tried setting it as a compile flag (`/D___STDC_VERSION__:199901L /D__STDC_VERSION__:199901L`) but that didn't help (it would also look very dirty if it actually did work).

Is there a way to avoid those warnings? E.g. setting `__STDC_VERSION__` in some other way. Or having more control over that section of flex generated code?

Comment: MSVC has never supported C99. You *could* select a later version using `/std:c11` or `/std:c17`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've just tried both compiling with `/std:c17` or `/D___STDC_VERSION__:201710L /D__STDC_VERSION__:201710L` but that didn't help.

Comment: Try `#ifndef __STDC__ #error This compiler sucks. #endif`. And from there ponder if it's worth the time to write all these macros on a non-C compiler which is not conforming to _anything_.

Comment: I believe you can compile with MSVC `/Za` to force it into "strictly dinosaur C" meaning C90. I don't think one can make it compile in a conforming mode for C99, C11 or C17. So maybe uninstall MSVC and take it from there.

Comment: @rturrado - "Of course" `__STDC_VERSION__` is only defined when compiling C code, not when compiling as C++...

Comment: Please see my answer. This MSVC warning has nothing to do with `__STDC_VERSION__` and is likely due to an `#include` directive enclosed within `%{` and `%}` that transitively includes `stdint.h`, which defines all the `INT8_MIN`, etc. macros. Content within `%{` and `%}` is copied into the Flex source *after* these Flex preprocessor directives, so these `stdint.h` macros get redefined. Include `stdint.h` within a `%top` block to silence this warning.

Comment: Is the lexer generating C code or C++ code?

Comment: @KeithThompson C code, but I'm using it in a C++ project.

Comment: @rturrado Are you compiling the generated code with a C compiler or with a C++ compiler? Possibly the generated code is valid C and valid C++. If you're compiling it with a C++ compiler, it's C++ code.

Comment: @KeithThompson I'm compiling with a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually ran into the same issue when working on my own Flex + Bison project.

The problem has nothing to do with the value of `__STDC_VERSION__`. The warning is for *macro* redefinition, e.g. for `INT8_MIN`, etc., which you can see when looking at the source file, e.g.

```c
/* Limits of integral types. */
#ifndef INT8_MIN
#define INT8_MIN               (-128)
#endif

/* ... */
```

These `INT8_MIN`, `INT16_MIN`, etc. macros are defined in `stdint.h`, so I am guessing that you are seeing this warning because your `.l` file has a block enclosed with `%{` and `}%` in the definitions section with some `#include` directives, one of which is transitively including `stdint.h`.

You can easily fix this by adding the following to your `.l` file's definition section:

```
%top{
  #include <stdint.h>
}
```

This can be replaced with `<cstdint>` if compiling the Flex output as C++.

The reason `%top` is necessary is because contents enclosed in `%{` and `}%`, at least for Flex 2.6.4 that I am using, are copied into the generated source *after* the `INT8_MIN`, `INT16_MIN`, etc. macros get defined, so any `#include` that transitively includes `stdint.h` will redefine those macros, which is what MSVC is complaining about and giving you this warning for.

In contrast, the `%top` block, as noted in the [Flex documentation](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Definitions-Section.html#Definitions-Section), will have its contents copied to the *top* of the generated source file before any Flex definitions. You need not put all your `#include` directives in a top block unless, e.g. for `stdint.h`, there is some particular need.

Comment: No problem, this had me stuck for a bit as well. It was only after I took a closer look at the generated Flex source did I realize what was going on. Then the documentation led me to `%top`.

Answer (score 2):

**See UPDATE below.**

You're compiling C++, not C. You can't assume that a C++ compiler will define `__STDC_VERSION__`, and it would be misleading to define it yourself.

The `<stdint.h>` and `<inttypes.h>` headers were introduced in C99, so testing for `__STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L` makes sense **in C code**.

Those headers, and their C++ equivalents `<cstdint>` and `<cinttypes>`, were introduced to C++ in the 2011 ISO C++ standard (adopted from C, of course). In C++ code, you should test that `__cplusplus` is defined and is greater than or equal to `201103L`.

Note that if you just want the type definitions and bounds macros, you should probably include `<cstdint>`. The `<cinttypes>` header includes `<cstdint>` and additionally defines a number of macros for use with `printf`, something that you probably don't need in C++.

**UPDATE:**

I see that the code in your question is generated by `flex`, and is being compiled as C++. The underlying cause is a bug in `flex`.

`flex` has a `--c++` option that tells it to generate code intended to be compiled as C++ rather than as C. Unfortunately, that generated C++ code still refers to the `__STDC_VERSION__` macro, which may or may not be defined by a C++ compiler. It should be referring to `__cplusplus` instead.

(There are updates in the [flex git repo](https://github.com/westes/flex) that fix this, but they do not yet appear in any released version. The most recent `flex` release, 2.6.4, is from 2017.)

The result of this is likely to be a false negative, i.e., the header doesn't detect that the implementation has `<cstdint>`, so it unnecessarily defines its own types `flex_int8_t` et al.

[phetdam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14227825/phetdam)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77120324/827263) likely provides a better workaround than mine, but I've tried here to provide some background information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The point is that the warnings come from Flex/Bison C generated code. That version check is generated code, is part of the lexer/parser files. My idea was to set `__STDC_VERSION__` from C++, as ugly as that could be, hoping it wouldn't do any harm. Adding `cstdint` as suggested by you and phetdam removed the warnings.

Comment: @rturrado If you added `#include <cstdint>` to the code *and it compiled*, then you're compiling it as C++, and I believe my answer is correct. Also, I wonder whether you really need to worry about pre-C++11 implementations that don't have `<cstdint>`. If not, you can drop the `#if`.

Comment: My project is C++, yes. The `#if` is Flex/Bison generated code. Do you think I could drop that code?

Comment: Ah, this gets tricky. (The code in your question is generated by flex, not by bison.) `flex` does have a `--c++` option, and it does cause it to generate code intended to be compiled as C++, but that code still looks at `__STDC_VERSION__`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Many thanks for your update @KeithThompson. Whereas phetdam's answer provides a nice and quick workaround, and well explained, your information makes the answer much more complete. BTW, to my knowledge, I'm not using that `--c++` flag. I'm invoking Flex via CMake's `flex_target`, and I am not using that `COMPILE_FLAG`.